# Is there a way to only pass specific jsonb properties to a SET in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I'm currently trying to create a new row of data using PostgreSQL with two columns `(ID, identity_data)`. Although, the original identity_data is a jsonb object with a lot of unnecessary properties, and I only want to include four `(full_name, avatar_url, provider_id, email_verified)` of the around 10 paths that are provided.

Currently, if you look at the SQL statement below, I delete the paths that I don't want to pass directly. The issue with this is that if there are any ever new paths, they won't be removed until I manually specify them for removal.

```sql
BEGIN -- Insert/Update clone of identity_data to public.identities table:
INSERT INTO public.identities (id, identity_data)
VALUES (new.id, new.identity_data::JSONB #- '{email}' #- '{iss}' #- '{sub}') ON CONFLICT (id) DO
UPDATE
SET id = excluded.id,
    identity_data = excluded.identity_data::JSONB #- '{email}' #- '{iss}' #- '{sub}';

RETURN NEW;

END;
```

Therefore, my question is if there's a way to explicitly select the keypaths I want to pass to the new identity_data column, instead of deleting the ones I currently know of.

Comment: Seems like you want to discard any existing data in the database for that id. Why don't you insert/update with a brand new json doc?

Comment: Side note: The schema of the JSON looks pretty static to me. You should consider not to abuse JSON but use relational means like (lookup and/or linking) tables and columns instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no operator as simple and convenient as `#-`, but you can write

```
INSERT INTO public.identities (id, identity_data)
VALUES (NEW.id, jsonb_build_object(
  'full_name', NEW.identity_data->'full_name',
  'avatar_url', NEW.identity_data->'avatar_url',
  'provider_id', NEW.identity_data->'provider_id',
  'email_verified', NEW.identity_data->'email_verified'
))
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
SET id = excluded.id,
    identity_data = excluded.identity_data;
```

or

```
INSERT INTO public.identities (id, identity_data)
VALUES (NEW.id, to_jsonb(
  SELECT *
  FROM jsonb_to_record(NEW.identity_data) AS id(full_name text, avatar_url text, provider_id int, email_verified boolean)
))
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
SET id = excluded.id,
    identity_data = excluded.identity_data;
```

<sup>(if you don't want to assert the types of the individual elements, `jsonb` works always)</sup>

or (most clearly expressing the intention)

```
INSERT INTO public.identities (id, identity_data)
VALUES (NEW.id, (
  SELECT jsonb_object_agg(key, value)
  FROM jsonb_each(NEW.identity_data)
  WHERE key IN ('full_name', 'avatar_url', 'provider_id', 'email_verified')
))
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
SET id = excluded.id,
    identity_data = excluded.identity_data;
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you very much! I also appreciate the multiple methods provided, it gives me a much better understanding of how PostgreSQL works